# Why two tags for Avatar?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

We currently have two tags for Avatar, [avatara](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatara) and [avatars](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatars). I thing one of then should be synonym of other. Currently i can't suggest synonym for this case, that's why raising it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All questions tagged with [avatara](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatara) have been retagged with [avatars](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatars). I didn't synonymize them, but if people re-create [avatara](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatara), I'll add a synonym.

Comment: I would think you'd want the tag to be avatara rather than avatar, since it's preferable to use the Sanskrit spelling rather than the Hindi spelling.  Otherwise we'd name our tags Ram, Shiv, etc.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan While in general I agree, I went with "avatar" in this case since "avatar" is the spelling that is by far the most widespread in English today (indeed, "avatar" is treated by most recent dictionaries as a proper English word).