# Can we unify tags 'incarnation', 'avatar' and 'avatars'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Can the mods unify tags [avatar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatar), [avatars](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatars) and [incarnation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incarnation)?

The current description of [avatars](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatars) is better than the other two, so better make them [synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) of the former.

Related question: [Why two tags for Avatar?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/204/2995)

Comment: [tag:avatars] is older, so it will be appropriate if Mods make [tag:avatar] its synonym, even its opposite doesn't seem bad. But incarnation can act differently too, so it should be kept.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes, avatar is better than the plural form. Not many questions use the incarnation tag, I think it was accidentally created by someone who didn't know about the other two. Incarnation tag should be either deleted or merged with other two. Even if we delete it [incarnation], there is no guarantee that someone new to the site will not create it again, so a synonym is more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just made [avatar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatar) and [incarnation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incarnation) synonyms of the [avatars](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatars) tag.